# Change email preferences for a Single Email Address in JIRA

Tags: configuration, jira

I'm on JIRA 4.1.2
When creating notifications, I'd like to notify a distribution group on our Exchange server, rather than create a JIRA user group. This is to avoid having to constantly update the group membership to reflect the distribution list as people move in and out of the list.

I can use the email address "distro@domain.com" successfully in my notification schemes as a Single Email Address, and everyone on the list receives emails as expected, but **the emails are plain text, when I would prefer HTML.**

Any individual user can update their email preferences, but **I can't figure out how to do this for an email address that doesn't correspond to a user on the system**. Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

EDIT

Now I'm even more confused. I found my way to the User Default Settings page, and the default for emails is listed as HTML, yet for the list I'm sending to, it's coming through as plain text.

Comment: You could actually create a "user" to represent the mailing list, then log in as that user and set your preferences? Unless JIRA is using LDAP authentication against AD, which I believe precludes you from creating users manually (at least in your version of JIRA). In the scenario where you can't create users manually, another possible option might be to adjust your LDAP config and move the baseDN to a higher level so that mailing lists and distribution groups are also visible to JIRA as "users".

Comment: We are using LDAP, unfortuantely, and I have no control over the LDAP config. We eventually just created a project role for the distro so the project admin could manage it directly. Non-optimal, but it looks like it's the solution for now.